# macOS macCatalyst WKWebView text selection behavior

Tags: wkwebview, textselection, mac-catalyst

The text selection behavior in a WKWebView seems wrong when compiled with macCatalyst. Normally it's possible to expand and contract a selection. In a WKWebView on macCatalyst it seems that it's impossible to contract the selection. This is happening with Xcode 11.4 (11E146) on macOS Catalina 10.15.4.

Is this just a bug? Or is there a workaround?

### Behavior in macCatalyst WKWebView

[image: macCatalyst behavior]

### Behavior in macOS Safari

[image]

The only thing the macCatalyst app does is load a WKWebView from a storyboard and then load a website using this line of code:

`webView.load(URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor")!))`

Any ideas?

Comment: I can confirm this and I posted a Feedback to Apple (FB7665924). The thing is, you don't need to show the problem in Safari, because WKWebView works on AppKit and also on iOS! It's only a Catalyst problem. Thanks for reporting this.

Comment: @StuFFmc Exactly! I posted the Safari video as a comparison, to show how it SHOULD behave :)